# Entity framework application crashing on other system,

Tags: entity-framework

i have made an application having entity framewrok. It is wpf application, now it runs fine on my computer, but when i run this application on another system it crashes, i debugged it on other system, exception came when i try to access data of entities, what could be problem,

[image]

[image]

Comment: And the exact exception and stacktrace is?

Comment: @leppie i have added screenshot, u can see it there,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The underlying provider failed on Open** either means that your connection string is incorrect or the application doesn't have access permission to the database (either SQL account specified in connection string or current user running the application).

Comment: "metadata=res://*/School.csdl|res://*/School.ssdl|res://*/School.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=\"data source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;attachdbfilename=D:\\School\\bin\\Debug\\School.mdf;integrated security=True;connect timeout=30;user instance=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework\""

this is my connection string, if there was some problem with connection string then i would get exception i connect to database, but at that time no exception come,

Comment: But you don't have control over connecting to database - EF context opens connection when it really needs it. Do you have SQLExpress installed on that system?

Comment: i found out the problem, it was sqlserver problem, fixed now,