# When installed on other PCs, C# WPF application (using entity framework) crashes while accessing local Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, entity-framework-6

I'm a newbie at wpf/c# and I developed an app connected to a local SQL server database using entity framework 6. I then made an installable for the app and tested it on different computers. It worked perfectly only on computers that have the same tools I used (Visual studios + Entity framwork tools). On other computers however, it crashes while trying to connect to the database. 
On these computers, I installed the right version of .NET framework, and Sql Server LocalDB, to no avail.
Here's my connection string just in case:

```
<add name="bdd2Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\bdd2.mdf;integrated security=True;connect timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I found some similar subject : [Entity framework application crashing on other system,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10927392/entity-framework-application-crashing-on-other-system/50172266#50172266)

I hope someone here can find a solution to my problem. Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked Event Viewer? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_Viewer

Comment: can you post the complete errormessage

Comment: Go to Event Viewer under Windows Logs->Application and check what issue you are getting for your application and post same here